# Grouping , cross section and sorting within cross section in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below data:

```
player_id   broadcast_month_id  runs_tier
67          201803              100s
67          201803              400s
67          201802              50s
67          201802              100s
67          201801              50s
67          201712              50s
67          201711              50s
67          201710              50s
67          201709              50s
67          201708              50s
67          201707              50s
67          201706              50s
67          201705              50s
67          201704              50s
67          201704              Others
```

I want to find out the latest runs_tier of each player in the dataset(This sample contains only 1 player, but the original dataset has around 500 players)

After reading in the data , I group by player_id and then cross section based on month and count the number of months in each tier as below:

```
run_tier = df_tier.pivot_table(index=['player_id'],columns=['runs_tier'],aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)\
                    .xs('broadcast_month_id', axis=1, drop_level=True)
```

I can get the tier where the player has been for max number of months as below:

```
run_tier['latest'] = df_tier.sort_values('player_id').groupby('player_id')['runs_tier'].tail(1).values
```

How do I get the latest tier of the player?
As per the above data, this players latest runs_tier is 100s
Can someone please help me with this?

```
household_id    100s    400s    50s Others  latest
67          2       1       11  1       100s
```

In case of duplicates like the first 2 records I take the top most one after sorting on date.

Comment: What do you mean by lastest? Sorting by date? How do you want to handle duplicate dates (`201803` in this example)

Comment: Hello @Susensio.. Please check the updated question and let me know if I could explain myself!

Comment: By topmost you mean 100s over 400s, right?

Comment: @Susensio .. Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first creating a *latest* column in *df_tier* with `groupby().transform()`, then run `pivot_table` without need of `.xs()`, followed by a new column assignment on a conditional filtered `groupby().min`:

```
# NEW COLUMN FOR LATEST broadcast_month_id
df_tier['latest'] = df_tier.groupby('player_id')['broadcast_month_id'].transform('max')

# PIVOT TABLE (with values arg)
run_tier = df_tier.pivot_table(index='player_id', columns='runs_tier', 
                               values='broadcast_month_id',
                               aggfunc='count', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None)

# NEW COLUMN FOR MIN runs_tier IN LATEST broadcast_month_id
run_tier['latest'] = df_tier[df_tier['latest']==df_tier['broadcast_month_id']]\
                           .groupby('player_id')['runs_tier'].min()

print(run_tier)
# runs_tier  100s  400s  50s  Others latest
# 67            2     1   11       1   100s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Parfait

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly...

First we must be able to sort `runs_tier`, so lets make it numerical, removing the `s` and setting `Others`to `nan`

```
>>> df
    broadcast_month_id  player_id runs_tier
0               201803         67      100s
1               201803         67      400s
2               201802         67       50s
3               201802         67      100s
4               201801         67       50s
..                 ...        ...       ...
10              201707         67       50s
11              201706         67       50s
12              201705         67       50s
13              201704         67       50s
14              201704         67    Others

[15 rows x 3 columns]

>>> df['numeric_tier'] = pd.to_numeric(df['runs_tier'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1]), errors='coerce')
>>> df
    broadcast_month_id  player_id runs_tier  numeric_tiers
0               201803         67      100s        100.000
1               201803         67      400s        400.000
2               201802         67       50s         50.000
3               201802         67      100s        100.000
4               201801         67       50s         50.000
..                 ...        ...       ...            ...
10              201707         67       50s         50.000
11              201706         67       50s         50.000
12              201705         67       50s         50.000
13              201704         67       50s         50.000
14              201704         67    Others            nan

[15 rows x 4 columns]
```

Now we can sort the dataframe, so that the first appearance of every player is the lastest topmost tier

```
df = df.sort_values(['player_id', 'broadcast_month_id', 'numeric_tiers'], ascending=[True, False, True])
```

and select only that first appearance:

```
>>> df = df[~df.duplicated('player_id')]
>>> df
   broadcast_month_id  player_id runs_tier  numeric_tiers
0              201803         67      100s        100.000
```

and then we can join it

```
>>> run_tier['lastest'] = df.set_index('player_id')['runs_tier'] 
>>> run_tier
runs_tier  100s  400s  50s  Others lastest                                                                                       
player_id                                                                                                                        
67            2     1   11       1    100s
```